# Why I cannot send more than one parameter to PHP from C++?

Tags: c++

I want to save data from C++ to PHP and here is what I have

```
    string cmd = "wget localhost/tem1.php?t=1&date=1&time=1";
    system((const char*) cmd.c_str());
```

as you can see I want to send parameter t, date and time, but it just sends t without the two others parameters, here is the output :

```
 --2016-11-21 20:56:45--  http://localhost/tem1.php?t=1
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5 [text/html]
Saving to: 'tem1.php?t=1'
```

Why it only takes t ? please help me to solve this problem 
* Notice :
When I write it in the link bar it will insert the data successfully
Thank you

Comment: what is the result of `to_string(temperature)`? Could there be a special character involved? Is `date` and `time` a valid string?

Comment: Have you tried outputting `cmd` to see what it is?

Comment: @Jeff temperature was a float but I converted it into string to be valid and when I print cmd it gives me this `tem1.php?t=4&date=3&time=1` and ignores the other parameters (date and time)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, there is no problem with it, it gives me `tem1.php?t=4&date=3&time=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is on a Unix/Linux system, the reason is the ampersand `&`. [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) executes your command by executing a shell

> The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3) as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```
>
> system() returns after the command has been completed.

The shell interprets `&` as putting the command into the background. To prevent this, you must wrap the argument with quotes

```
string cmd = "wget \"localhost/tem1.php?t=" + to_string(temperature) + "&date=" + date + "&time=" + time + "\"";
```

This tells the shell to leave the ampersand alone.